# .htaccess program slash getting added to url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write the following `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^follower/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ follower.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```

But it executing like `follower.php/?username=example` , So my page CSS getting problem .. Total layout getting disturbed !

Any solution to this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some other rule that is adding a missing trailing slash? Because the rule you posted won't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape your slashes

```
RewriteRule ^follower\/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\/?$ follower.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Why would that help with a slash getting added to the end of `follower.php`?

Comment: Don't know exactly, but it happened to me once. When I escaped everything, it worked.

Comment: Mihai lorga can i have your gmail , i will show u demo on my server

Comment: Check you FB , i have added you ;)